# How can I display this image at its original size, but only display it within a specific element?

Tags: javascript, css, image, html

Here's the code I'm currently working with: http://jsfiddle.net/gEMCm/

I'm trying to make an image appear at its original height and width, but to only be visible inside a specific element (the green-bordered one in the fiddle), and to also make the image movable while still only being visible within the specific element. An example of something that works the way I want this to work, is Facebook's way of letting you set a profile image. When you set an image as your profile image on Facebook, it lets you move the image around and choose a specific area of it to be visible. I want to do something like that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/gEMCm/1/)

Add `overflow: hidden;` to the wrapper div.

Comment: cool!! now i am trying for moving it using YUI.thanx

Answer (score 3):

You might be better off setting the image as a background image and using background-position styles/css to align the image how you want.  As for being able to move the image, have you searched for an existing js file for that?  If not, did you at least look at the facebook code?  You MIGHT be able to find it by digging into facebook's js file.

Comment: hmm..you are correct i should try that.
ok i have seen jquery and yui for moving images.
I should take a look at facebook js.

Comment: how do you change background position dynamically in js